# Android SQLite onUpgrade = force close

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is the situation. I'm upgrading my database adding a single column. The upgrade appears to go fine. I can see the new column added but the problem is when upgrading my app from the older to the new version w/ new DB I get force close. The force close seems to occur when accessing the new column. If I do a fresh install however I get no force closes and app works as expected.

My on upUpgrade looks as such:

```
  @Override   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase notes_db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {    if (oldVersion == 29) {
    notes_db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Notes ADD COLUMN Priority text");
    notes_db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Todo ADD COLUMN Priority text");
    notes_db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Todo_keys ADD COLUMN Priority text");    } else {
    notes_db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NOTES_TABLE);
    notes_db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TODO_TABLE);
    notes_db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TODO_KEYS_TABLE);
    onCreate(notes_db);    }      }
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

This is where I believe it fails...

```
11-23 14:37:06.210: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1647): Shutting down VM
11-23 14:37:06.210: WARN/dalvikvm(1647): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7e8)
11-23 14:37:06.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 14:37:06.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-23 14:37:06.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at com.flufflydelusions.app.extensive_notes_donate.Notes$TaskSimpleCursorAdapter.getView(Notes.java:1065)
11-23 14:37:06.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
11-23 14:37:06.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
11-23 14:37:06.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
11-23 14:37:06.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8173)
11-23 14:37:06.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
11-23 14:37:06.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
11-23 14:37:06.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
11-23 14:37:06.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
11-23 14:37:06.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8173)
11-23 14:37:06.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
11-23 14:37:06.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
11-23 14:37:06.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8173)
11-23 14:37:06.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1647):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
```

Line 1065 is the catch statement and priority1 is the new column I added..

String priority1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(databaseHelper.DB_COLUMN_PRIORITY));

```
        if (priority1.equals("Low")) {
            try {
                String low_pref = preferences.getString("low_priority_color", "Default");
                if (!low_pref.equals("Default")){
                    priority_text.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(low_pref, 16)+0xFF000000);
                    priority_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    priority_text.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFe640);
                    priority_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }} catch (Exception e) { 
                    errorText = e.getMessage();
                    themeError();
                }                   
            }
```

Comment: can you please show the stacktrace?

Comment: There you go. That getView is where it is accessing the new column. If I take the statement out of there it will run..but obviously I need it.

Comment: ok, what about Notes.java and the context of 1065 line?

Comment: Updated it with 1065 which is the catch statement

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Are priority_text and preferences != null?

Comment: I solved it guys it was because the upgrade didn't have a default value..THanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. New column had null value